# Overloading operator+ in a template class with 2 templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, operator-overloading

I have the following templatе:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class equationSolution {
public:
    T1 a, b, c;
    float d;
    
    friend ostream& operator<< <T1, T2>(ostream& str, const equationSolution<T1, T2>& ov);

    equationSolution<T1,T2>& operator+=(const equationSolution<T1, T2>& ov, const int& value);

    equationSolution() : a(0), b(0), c(0) {}
    equationSolution(T1 a1, T1 b1, T1 c1) : a(a1), b(b1), c(c1) {
        a = a;
        b = b;
        c = c;
        d = pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c;
    }
}
```

I managed to overload the output

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& str, const equationSolution<T1, T2>& ov)
{
    str << "(" << ov.a << "," << ov.b << "," << ov.c << ")";
    return str;
}
```

But with the operator `+=` I have difficulties.
That's what I did:

```
friend equationSolution<T1, T2>& operator += (const equationSolution<T1, T2>& ov, const int& value) {
    ov.a += value;
    ov.b += value;
    ov.c += value;

    return ov;
}
```

But I have error:

```
binary "operator + =" has too many parameters
```

Comment: i wana doo smth like that  
equationSolution<int, double> intSolution2(1.0, 2.1, 3);
intSolution += 2;

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but in your constructor you have e.g. `a = a`, which will be equal to `this->a = this->a`, i.e. it assigns the member variable `a` to the member variable `a`. It makes no sense, especially since you correctly initialize the member variables in the constructor initializer list. Also, what is the template argument `T2` for? You don't seem to use it anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All assignment operator overloads (all of them) must be member functions, and as such they should take only *one* argument: The right-hand side of the operator.

That is, an expression like

```
foo += bar;
```

will be translated as

```
foo.operator+=(bar);
```

You declare the operator function as a member function, but using two arguments. Then you define (implement) the function as a non-member `friend` function, which is not allowed. The error you mention is from the declaration.

What you should do is something like

```
equationSolution& operator+=(const int& value)
{
    // TODO: Implement the actual logic
    return *this;
}
```